# Paramiko ssh to windows with ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054]

Tags: paramiko, python-3.5

My code below works fine with Linux servers but the script doesn't work with Windows 2008 Server with OpenSSH installed. I have also tested to ssh with teraterm with the same username, password, ipaddress and port22 it worked fine as well.

I am getting the below error.

```
 C:\Users\>python auto-ssh_v1.py
    Socket exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (10054)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "auto-ssh_v1.py", line 71, in <module>
    results = executer.execute()
    File "auto-ssh_v1.py", line 53, in execute
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(self.command)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 405, in exec_command
    chan.exec_command(command)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 60, in _check
    return func(self, *args, **kwds)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 229, in exec_command
    self._wait_for_event()
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 1086, in _wait_for_event
    raise e
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1726, in run
    ptype, m = self.packetizer.read_message()
    File "C:\U\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 386, in read_message
    header = self.read_all(self.__block_size_in, check_rekey=True)
    File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 249, in read_all
    x = self.__socket.recv(n)
    ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

The code is

```
  #Modules
    import paramiko

    #Variables
    USER = 'Administrator'
    PSWD = 'Passw0rd'

    #Classes and Functions
    class InputReader:
        def __init__(self, commands_path, hosts_path):
            self.commands_path = commands_path
            self.hosts_path = hosts_path

        def read(self):
            self.commands = self.__readlines(self.commands_path)
            self.hosts = self.__readlines(self.hosts_path)

        def __readlines(self, path):
            with open(path) as f:
            return [v.strip() for v in f.readlines()] #List comprehension

    class CommandExecuter:
        def __init__(self, host, command):
            self.host = host
            self.command = command

        def execute(self):
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            ssh.connect(self.host, username=USER, password=PSWD)

            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(self.command)

            errors = stderr.readlines()
            if len(errors) != 0:
               raise Exception(errors)

            lines = [v.strip() for v in stdout.readlines()]
            ssh.close()
            return lines

    #Main Procedure
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        reader = InputReader("commands.txt", "systems.txt")
        reader.read()

        for h in reader.hosts:
            for c in reader.commands:
                executer = CommandExecuter(h, c)
                results = executer.execute()

                print("{0}({1}):".format(h, c))
                for i in results:
                    print(i)
                    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run paramiko line by line to ssh to your windows server and see the trace.

Hope that will help,

Trinh

Comment: Trinh, Thank you very much for your comment!! i will share the result of running the code line by line^^